# PHP Function to Compare Strings in Two Arrays for Relevancy

Tags: php, arrays, text, compare

Suppose you have two arrays:

```
$keywords=("stuff", "things", "an important phrase", "something to keep in mind"); 
$data = ("lots of junk about things and stuff", "some disorganized data pertaining to a phrase");
```

Assuming they will almost never be of the same count and that, as above, the actual keywords will be buried in junk if present at all, what's the best to iterate over each value of $data, compare it for general relevancy to the $keyword value, and then, if it is found to be generally relevant, store it in a new array?

I have experimented with foreach loops and for loops going through each array and using similar_text on each element but I've had no luck so far.

I feel like this is close:

```
unction compare_arrays_for_relevancy ($array1, $array2) {
if (is_array($array1) && is_array($array2)) {
    echo "Both valid arrays";
    } else {
        echo "Not Arrays";
        }
    foreach ($array1 as $key) {
        foreach ($array2 as $key2){
            echo "<pre>";
            similar_text($key, $key2, $percent);
            echo $percent; 
            echo "</pre>";
            if ($percent > 50){
                $relevant[] = $key2; 
        } else{
            echo "Not relevant"; 
        }

}
```

}
}

Ok - I added the percent option....closer...but im interested in the array values that were somewhat matched...

Comment: what have you tried?  for each index of data, can't you just iterate over each index of keywords and use string searching functions?

Comment: paste what you have tried...basically 2 for`s and a minimum percentage and an array append should do it

Comment: lol - ok - answering my own question here as I go - I spent hours on this last night and couldn't get it - now it's working - must have slept on it.